# Get a group from layerTreeRoot using its unique id using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, grouping, unique-id

I am having trouble when loading some layers in QGIS. I want to place them in specific groups and sub-groups but a problem occurs when multiple groups and sub-groups have the same name. The only way I can retrieve a group or a sub-group is by using its name:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup('group_name')
group.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

Is there a way to retrieve a group or a sub-group using a unique identifier? If you create these groups in QGIS:

[image]

and execute the following code in the python console you will see that QGIS always places the layer under the first group it finds to have that name.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup('group A')
uri = "point?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "Scratch point layer", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
group.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

but instead, I want to place it here:

[image]

Comment: `findGroup(name)` returns the first found with the name so you can't expect it to be placed in a specific group if you have multiple group named the same, at least the way you tried

Answer (score 5):

I've written [a script](https://github.com/kadirsahbaz/SUHULET/blob/main/SUHULET.py) to access easily to layer(s) and group(s) in QGIS Layer Panel.

Here's the group part:

```
def G(group_path: str = None):
    """
    Return the group given in path
    If group_path is None, returns root
    """

    group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

    if group_path:
        groups =  group_path.strip("/").split('/')
        for g in groups:
            group = group.findGroup(g)
            if not group:
                raise Exception(f"Not found")

    return group


layer = QgsVectorLayer('None', "layer", "memory")

group = G('group B/group A')
group.addLayer(layer)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This piece of code is useful. I wasn't aware of the possibility to find a group within a group but still, it's not exactly what I am looking for because the same problem will occur when I have a group with a sub-group that have the same names as another group with a sub-group. ie in the above example group B was renamed to group A. QGIS needs to provide a unique id for all groups just like it does for layers